# sql count of sum of agrouped column

Tags: php, mysql

I know im asking a silly question, but need a efficient answer: here is my sql:

```
"SELECT STATUS, COUNT(STATUS) FROM CONTENT GROUP BY STATUS

  +------------+---------------+
  | STATUS     | COUNT(STATUS) |
  +------------+---------------+
  | Converted  |          4547 |
  | Received Q |           525 |
  | Signed     |             1 |
  | Uploaded   |            15 |
  +------------+---------------+
```

The result is absolutely fine but i need he total or **sum** of the **count(Status)** too like 4547+525+1+15 sum up, but how can i do that with easy solution as in my db i have millions of data.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rollup` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

```
SELECT STATUS, COUNT(STATUS) FROM CONTENT GROUP BY STATUS WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: thns it works but total namd as null, can i change that?

Comment: Well thats the default behaviour of roll up, You can also use an outer query for the final select and use `ifnull()` to convert `STATUS` value having null to something you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using result from the main query as inner query. Though this is little dummy way of doing this.

```
    SELECT STATUS, STATUS_COUNT, SUM(STATUS_COUNT) AS TOTAL FROM (SELECT STATUS, COUNT(STATUS) AS STATUS_COUNT FROM CONTENT GROUP BY STATUS) AS X
```

Comment: nop its not working its just returning only one status